# How to create a UIView from a UITableViewCell button click on a separate UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, delegates

I'm working on an iOS app in Xcode/Swift and I'm trying to add a subview `UISendViewButton` in my `MainViewController` when a `UITableViewCell` button is clicked in a separate `UITableViewController` (which itself is embedded in a `UIView`). Basically, the concept is that of a "send post" button like in Instagram: the user will click a paper airplane button and a separate list of friends appears (`UIView` -> `UITableViewController`). Next to the list of contacts, there is a button (`customButton`) that the user can click to choose which friends to send it to. What I want is to have a "Send" button (`UIViewButton`) appear ONLY if the user decides to click the button (`customButton`) next to their friends' name.

I was able to make the `UITableViewController` appear by embedding it within a `UIView` and then adding that as a subview to my `MainViewController`, but when I click the `customButton` in the `UITableViewCell` class, nothing happens. I would like for a new `UIViewButton` (in my `MainViewController`) to appear when I click the `customButton`.

So basically I wanted to know how to have these two controllers communicate. The controller which houses the `UITableViewCell` button is the one that is provided by Xcode's library: `UITableViewController` -> `UITableView` -> `UITableViewCell` which is itself embedded within a `UIView`.

I tried using a delegate on the `UITableViewCell` class below:

```
import UIKit
public protocol CustomCellDelegate: class {

func customButtonClick()

}

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var customButton: UIButton!

    weak var delegate: CustomCellDelegate?


    @IBAction func customButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
      delegate?.customButtonClick()

    } 
  .. }
```

And corresponding code on the `MainViewController` here:

```
import UIKit
class MainViewController: UIViewController, CustomCellDelegate {

@IBOutlet var UIViewButton: UIView!

 func customButtonClick() {
      self.UIViewButton.frame = CGRect (x:20, y: 300, width: 369, height: 46)
      self.view.addSubview(UIViewButton)

  } }
```

I know that `CustomTableViewCell` is within two different controllers (`CustomTableView`, `CustomTableViewController`), so I was thinking there may be a delegate issue within one of those/I may need to add another delegate for those controllers but I'm not sure how. I've managed to change the `customButton` icon in `CustomTableViewCell` so I know that it's clickable, I just can't seem to get it to delegate or communicate with the `MainViewController` and have the `UIViewButton` appear. I'm sorry for the confusion and inconvenience, any help with this would be greatly appreciated as I'm a beginner to coding. Thanks so much!! ^__^

UPDATE:

`CustomTableViewController:`

```
public protocol ContactListTableViewControllerDelegate: class {
func showSendButton() }

class CustomTableViewController: UITableViewController, CustomCellDelegate {

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "likesCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    cell.delegate = self } 

 func customButtonClick() {
    delegate?.showSendButton()
} }
```

`MainViewController`:

```
extension MainViewController: ContactListTableViewControllerDelegate {
func showSendButton() {
    
       self.UISendButton.frame = CGRect (x:20, y: 300, width: 369, height: 46)
    self.view.addSubview(UISendButton)
} }
```

Comment: How do you connect the main controller to the cell's delegate variable?

Comment: @PhillipMills thanks so much for responding! I put the CustomCellDelegate in the MainViewController's class so it looks like this: "class MainViewController: UIViewController, CustomCellDelegate {" is that what you meant?

Comment: No, that just declares that your MainViewController is capable of being a CustomCellDelegate.  What needs to happen is that something tells each cell what object its `delegate` variable should point to.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that your UI is similar to the image below.

[image]

For this, I would do the following

1. Declare a protocol that will let you know when to show or hide the 'Send' button.
   For example

   ```
    protocol ContactListTableViewControllerDelegate: class {
        func showSendButton() 
        func hideSendButton()
    }
   ```
2. Make the first view controller the delegate for the table view controller class
3. You have already created a protocol for picking up tap events on the button inside the cell. Optionally you need to add the cell too as a parameter, so that the delegate knows which cell was clicked.

   ```
    public protocol CustomCellDelegate: class {

        func customButtonClick(cell: CustomTableViewCell)

    }
   ```
4. When creating each cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath method, make the table view controller the delegate for the cell

   ```
    cell.delegate = self
   ```
5. Implement the delegate method in the table view controller subclass

   ```
    func customButtonClick(cell: CustomTableViewCell) {
        // Find the index path for the clicked cell
        // You should have an array for storing the indices of selected cells
        // Check if the index is already in the array. If yes, remove it from 
        //the array (deselection)
        // If no, add the index to the array(selection)
        // Check the count of the array
        // If it is > 0, it means at least one cell is selected. Call the 
        // delegate method
        // to show button
        delegate?.showSendButton()
        // Else call delegate method to hide send button
        delegate?.hideSendButton()
    }
   ```

Comment: I have made many assumptions regarding your setup in this answer for completeness. Please let me know if you need more clarity

Comment: thanks so much for responding so quickly! I updated my original answer above for your convenience, but am still having difficulty with it. I followed your instructions and put the delegates in the right places (I think) but still can't get the button/view to show up. I feel like I'm missing a delegate in the MainViewController? Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Let's do this step by step as we seem to be missing some basic info regarding the problem. In which class have you placed the protocol CustomCellDelegate ?

Comment: Okay thanks. I placed the protocol CustomCellDelegate in the CustomTableViewController class outlined above in my update like this: " class CustomTableViewController: UITableViewController, CustomCellDelegate { "

Comment: Ok. This line in your code confused me "class MainViewController: UIViewController, CustomCellDelegate"

Comment: Here we need only the CustomTableViewController to be the cell's delegate and the method customButtonClick should be implemented in that class

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, that was the previous version before I updated it with your help. And okay, but then how can I access the MainViewController's UIViewButton to appear? It won't let me drag it in as an IBOutlet to CustomTableViewController since UIViewButton is nested in MainViewController's scene dock and not CustomTableViewController's. The reason why I originally put it there is because I want the "Send" button to appear outside of the UITableView contact list.

Comment: As mentioned, once you get the delegate method called in the CustomTableViewController, you call the appropriate method in its own delegate, which in this case is the MainViewController.  The MainViewController can offcourse access the button object and set it's visiblity

Comment: Also please rename the object UIViewButton to something that tells readers of your code about the purpose of the button.

Comment: Okay thanks so for your continued help. I tried setting up the MainViewController as the delegate, but it still won't show up. I even tried just changing the text of something on the MainViewController but it still doesn't seem to communicate. The CustomTableViewController and the contact list is itself embedded in a final UIView and so I think the issue is happening there. Does the UIView need to have something or its own delegate in order to access or communicate between the CustomTableViewController and the MainViewController?

Comment: Delegate mechanism is chained here. That is once the event originates in the table view via button click, you need to transfer that information up the chain until you reach the main view controller. I would suggest starting at the cell click event and successively checking if the all the links in the chain are working. I see that you are calling the cel's delegate when the button is clicked. Can you post the implementation of the delegate method in CustomTableViewController

Comment: Also I am not sure how you have embedded the view controller inside a view. It should be the other way around. UIViewControllers have their own UIViews. UIViews can have sub views which are also objects of UIView.

Comment: Oh, are you using view controller containment (with parent and child view controllers) ?

Comment: Hi thanks so much for the help. I'm starting to understand the chain, and I think the chain works as I've worked with delegates in the past but there is definitely a break in between the links. And yes, I added a container view to the MainViewController's scene dock and then did an Embed Segue for the CustomTableViewController as Xcode didn't let me put the CustomTableViewController inside of the MainViewController's Scene Dock. I didn't know how to programmatically instantiate the CustomTableViewController on top of the MainViewController so that was the route I opted for.